# Android Studio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, runtime-error

My app is supposed to be able to delete data from a database. However, whenever I try to run it from both an emulator and my phone, I get the error above and a black screen. I've tried changing emulators, invalidating cache + restarting, and syncing the gradle files. I've seen other answers, but they either have resulted in errors or are above my skill level. Can someone please explain the fix for this to me?